# Request entity too large when passing POST data in curl

Tags: apache, curl, http-status-code-413, fastcgi++, fedora-29

I have a fastcgi++ service. It takes 4 parameters through POST because one of them is a password. My sample input is 61 characters. This is how I am calling my service:

```
curl --data 'name=test&address=abc&phoneNumber=0987654321&password=test123' http://localhost/cgi-bin/add-user.fcg
```

I get this error: **413 Request Entity too large**. Based on my research I found that it means apache was expecting a smaller body than it got. So, I added `LimitRequestBody 0` to httpd.conf (I am not in production environment). But apache still complains that the request entity is too large.

I added -v to curl and this is the output:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /cgi-bin/add-user.fcg HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 60
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 60 out of 60 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
< Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2019 03:48:09 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Fedora) mod_fcgid/2.3.9
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head><body><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></body></html>
```

This is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>


    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

#I added the line below
LimitRequestBody 0
```

This it the fcgid.conf:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl

Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
```

Comment: add `-v` to curl, what do you get?

Comment: Did you restart apache/php handler after changing conf?

Comment: Yes @Harikrishnan. I did it again after reading your comment. Nothing happened. The results are the same

Comment: Added the -v output in the question @hanshenrik

Comment: 60 bytes is too low to trigger 413 error. I think your apache is misconfigured.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. I added my httpd.conf in the question @Harikrishnan

Comment: Looks like you are using FastCGI. There should be extra conf for that.

Comment: Though I didn't configure the fastcgi. It is the default. I am adding it @Harikrishnan

Comment: Try changing `LimitRequestBody 0`  to `LimitRequestBody 1024000`

Comment: Same result. It makes no difference @Harikrishnan

Comment: Here's a crucial hint: That's not the compiled-in 413 error page from Apache. The DOCTYPE is wrong and the text has other differences.  You can stop worrying about `LimitRequestBody`. It also doesn't appear to be synthesized by mod_fcgid.  so I'd suggest sending test requests to a simple e.g. perl fcgi w/ otherwise  same config so you can narrow it down.

Comment: I have not written that error in my fastcgi script. For example, if I send in no POST parameters, my script runs fine. It gives me error in json that I defined. @covener

Comment: The script does not run as soon as I have even one character in data. @covener. It works otherwise

Comment: I made a sample script which took one POST parameter "q" (for query). The script would print "Query not submitted" when q was not given. The script works when q is not given but returns the same 413 error page when i pass q. @covener

Comment: Try without php or fcgid to narrow it down

Comment: What can i do without php or fcgi? I am sorry but I am total newbie in networking @covener

Comment: I got a crucial hint. I enabled mod_dumpio and ran `curl -v -d 'q=098765' http://localhost/cgi-bin/main.fcg`. (main.fcg takes one post param q (for query) and prints it on the screen (text/plain)); my error_log shows `mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ::1:36598] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): q=098765` means, apache got the right query @covener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have mentioned that I was using the fastcgi++ library. As @[covener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98959/covener) mentioned, the 413 page was not apache's. It turns out that it was fastcgi++. I should have read the docs first. It clearly mentions [here](https://github.com/eddic/fastcgipp/blob/ad22f4e9ae23ff3577777364209ff1970115f7cd/include/fastcgi%2B%2B/request.hpp#L105) that POST is not enabled by default. Adding a constructor to my class and calling the Request constructor with the max size of POST requests I wanted, solved the problem.

P.S. thanks a lot @[hansherik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik) for all the hours of debugging you have done for me.

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer, but too big for a comment)

what do you get if you run this php script?

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
$ch=curl_init('http://localhost/cgi-bin/add-user.fcg');
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'curl/7.61.1',CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1));
$post_str="";
for($i=0;$i<61;++$i){
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_POST=>1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post_str,
));
curl_exec($ch);
$code=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
echo "bytes: {$i} code: {$code}\n";
$post_str.="a";
}
curl_close($ch);
echo "finished loop";
```

Comment: End of script output before headers

Comment: @Hemil i doubt it, but okay.. i'm bored, can you contact me on Facebook or Discord now? wanna see it for myself - https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile

Comment: I sent a request on discord as `Hemilr`